# Attribute 'tools:node' is not allowed here

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play-console

I do want to display ads in my Flutter app, and I do have declared it in the Play console:

[image]

However, I get this error in the Play console after uploading the bundle:

```
Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.
```

I did some research and found that I have to declare the permission in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file located at: `android/app/src/main` so here's how it looks:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    ....
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
    ....
</manifest>
```

But I get the same exact error again. Then I saw a post here on SO saying that I have to do it like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove" />
```

However, Android Studio tells me `Attribute tools:node is not allowed here`?

I use Android Studio version 2023.1.1 Patch 2 on Windows 11.